# Throw error in react.js project 8001 address already in use

Tags: node.js, mongodb

throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error :listen EADDRINUSE::address already in use :::8001

Emitted 'error' event on Server instance

Answer (score 0):

Because you are already using this port, If you  for example are going to install a package in visual studio code terminal and you want to stop the port running press Ctrl+C in terminal first, install the package then run your proccess again in terminal. Also If you  close visual studio code and you didn´t stop the process you should check how to kill a proccess in a particular port according to your operating system.